# Synapse notebook - reference to unpublished notebook

Tags: azure-synapse

I was trying to using %run to refer to an unpublished notebook, based on here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#reference-unpublished-notebook, this feature seems been disabled by default, does anyone know how to enable it? Many thanks.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Why not publish it?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not released yet. Expecting this feature to get release in MARCH end or APRIL early weeks.

This feature only works when running notebook on UX interactively. In pipeline you still need to publish it. You can find an option in notebook properties to enable this. Please refer to the image below:

[image]

Comment: is this feature released yet?